# Shading sections of a graph using R

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

So I have this data

```
   Time  Average    Test n    se
1    20  5.80000     Exp 9 0.120
2    40  6.10000     Exp 9 0.145
3    60  6.40000     Exp 9 0.188
4    80  6.70000     Exp 9 0.990
5   100  7.00000     Exp 9 0.440
6   120  7.70000     Exp 9 0.320
7    20  8.47000 Control 9 0.500
8    40  9.31700 Control 9 0.880
9    60 10.24870 Control 9 0.900
10   80 11.27357 Control 9 0.330
11  100 12.40093 Control 9 0.456
```

And I used the following code to plot it

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Time, y=Average, colour=Test)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Average-se, ymax=Average+se), width=0.2) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()
```

I want to shade particular sections in this graph. For example I want to shade the portion from 20 to 30 s. Is this possible to do in `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description, it's not exactly clear what you had in mind.  How about this: ?

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Time, y=Average, colour=Test)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=20,xmax=30,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),fill="pink",colour=NA,alpha=0.05) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Average-se, ymax=Average+se), width=0.2) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image: Example of vertical shading]

Comment: Thanks this is fine! I was wondering is it possible to change the colour? For example can the shade be pink instead?

Comment: Sure, you just need to specify the `fill` aesthetic.  See the updated answer.  Note that the `colour` value here refers to the outline color of the rectangle, but I thought it looked better being "transparent" (`colour=NA`).