# How can I create a Legend in R with ggplot2 for marked areas in the graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

Hey guys I'am trying to plot some spectral data, which I modified. I'am using `ggplot2` for the graphs.

````
graphik <- ggplot(data = spektrum2,  mapping=aes(x=y0000,y=x0001))+
  geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=285, xmax=290.3, ymin=min(x0001-.5), ymax=max(x0001+0.5),`fill="orange")) +
  #geom_text(aes(x=288+(288.5-290.3)/2, y=min(x0001)+(max(x0001)-min(x0001))/2, label="Carbon-edge",color="brown",vjust=-30), size=4) +
  geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=524, xmax=539, ymin=min(x0001-.5), ymax=max(x0001+0.5), fill="yellow")) +
  #geom_text(aes(x=539+(524-539)/2, y=min(x0001)+(max(x0001)-min(x0001))/2, label="Oxygen-edge",color="brown",vjust=-30), size=4) +
  geom_line(mapping=aes(color="blue"))+  
  labs(title = "Isoprene#8", title.position="center")+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(270, 570), ylim = c(0, 1.4))+
  ylab("Optical Desity [-]")+
  xlab("Energy [eV]")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(seq(270,580, 20)))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(seq(0,2, 0.1)))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  stat_peaks(aes(color = "red"),shape = 20, span = 14, size = 2)+ 
  stat_label_peaks(geom = "label_repel", span = 10, segment.color = "black", size = 3, vjust = 1, nudge_y = 0.8, direction = "y") + 
  scale_color_identity()+
  scale_fill_identity()

print(graphik)```
````

I marked specific areas with `geom_rect`. The first area is orange and the second yellow. Now I would create a legend, but I don't know how. The legend should show the name of my spectrum with color in this case blue and the marked areas orange and blue.
Unfortunately I can not uplode a picture here.

Comment: well, without data nor plot, one can only guess. but here's a guy who got an answer on his question on setting up a legend for his geom_rect's, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652257/adding-legend-to-geom-rect-in-r-ggplot2

Comment: Try with `scale_fill/color_identity(guide = "legend")`. By default ´scale_xxx_identity` will not produce a legend.

Comment: Thanks a lot @stefan it works fine!! :)

Comment: Thanks @Sirius it is a good information!